# Remove items in list before a matched item groovy

Tags: list, groovy

If I have a list like so:

```
def list = ['a','b','c','d','c']
```

and I want to remove all items before the first *c*, how can I easily do this with groovy?

I'm looking for a one line answer if it exists :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def list = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']

assert ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'] == list.dropWhile{it != 'c'}
assert ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'] == list.drop(list.indexOf('c'))
assert ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'] == list[list.indexOf('c')..-1]    
assert ['c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'] == list.subList(list.indexOf('c'), list.size())
assert ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'] == list
```

The main `list` is always preserved. You get a new list every time.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

```
def start = list.findIndexOf { it ==~ /(?i)c/ }
commands = list[start..-1]
```

I could make it one line, but it's not as readable.